# FileSaveDialog changing my current working directory path

Tags: winforms, savefiledialog

I am new to winforms and facing one problem in my application. I am trying to show the user to save a file using **SaveFileDialog** control on my form. But as soon as the user chooses his directory and saves his file, my next code which uses **Directory.getCurrentDirectory()** fails to point to my working directory. It seems that SaveFileDialog is causing problem here.

For eg:- I have these lines of code -

```
MessageBox.Show( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory( ) ); // output: C:\TestSamples\TestApp\Bin\Debug
fdSave.ShowDialog( ); // fdSave is SaveFileDialog control which will show to save file
MessageBox.Show( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory( ) ); //output: C:\Program files\outputDir (This is the path chosen by user to save file in previous saveDialog.)
```

Is there any solution for this so that my current working directory does not get changed or should I keep a variable to store my current working directory before saveDialog is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a possible answer in the comments on [Raymond Chen's excellent blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/12/10089878.aspx):

> in the class System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog, there is a property 'RestoreDirectory'

Comment: Yup.  Which is just an example of the more general case of "oops, some code I didn't write is changing the working directory".  Use full paths.

Comment: @Hans Passant, good advice. Have you thought of asking the OP why that isn't a possibility? Or even leaving the advice as an answer?

Comment: I think the OP will be happier with your answer.

Comment: @Hans Passant, remember that the OP will only see the answer once, but Google will see it forever. It's always good to see a mix of pragmatic short-term fixes and best practices.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use the [Application.StartupPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx) if you always wanted it to point to the bin directory